# Receiving multiple files, not just one, in a Shortcut on macOS 12 Monterey

Tags: automator, shortcuts-app

I'm porting an Automator action to Shortcuts and I'm having a bit of trouble. Here's my Automator action:

[image: oxipng Quick Action in Big Sur's Automator]

The snippet of zsh inside is:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    /usr/local/bin/oxipng -pD -o max "$f"
done
```

This Automator action lets me select a bunch of PNG files in Finder, right-click on them, choose `Services → oxipng -pD -o max`, and after a while, the files will be smaller thanks to [oxipng](https://github.com/shssoichiro/oxipng).

However, when I try to port it to Shortcuts, I'm a bit stuck. Here's what I have so far, in a Shortcut with a less nerdy name, an adjusted path to oxipng, and some debugging printfs:

[image: oxipng with libdeflate Shortcut]

As an aside, the `Shortcut Input` to the `Run Shell Script` action is `Type: File`, `Get: File Path`. By default, names passed in don't have the full file path or file extensions.

When I run the Shortcut with only one image selected, everything runs just as it used to. However, if I select a bunch of files, I'm prompted to choose only one of them. The prompt looks like this:

[image: Shortcut prompting me for paths]

How can I get my Shortcut to process all the files that I've passed to it?

Comment: It works for me: the only difference I can see is that i've used "Ask for Files" if there's no input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid processing a list of file paths in your shell script just loop over the input with *Repeat with Each* and pass each file path as the script argument with a Shortcuts variable. Quote it to keep spaces and other special characters present in the path.
[image: A screenshot of Shortcuts looping over multiple files]

Comment: This is much, much cleaner than the accepted answer. I used it for a slightly different Shortcut (`-pZ -o max`) where each item is expected to take a long time and I want one notification per item processed.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue while trying to port some Automator scripts to Shortcuts. So frustrating. I *really* hope there's a better approach than the workaround I came up with.

Here's what ended up working for me:

#### 1. Start with the "Combine Text" action

[image]

#### 2. Right click on "Text List," hover over "Select Variable" and choose "Shortcut Input"

[image]

#### 3. Left click on "Shortcut Input" and select "File Path". Make sure "With New Lines" is selected

This will combine the input file paths with newlines.

[image]

#### 4. Convert the newline-separated filename input into an array and iterate over it.

I tried a few other ways of combining / replacing the file paths prior to the shell script (e.g. sending them in as quoted strings separated by a space -- "file 1" "file 2") to see if I could make "$@" work as it normally does, but I gave up after a while. No matter what I did "$1" looked just like "$@". So I ended up with something custom.

---

#### Shell script

Here's the shell script for easy copy/paste (should work on bash and zsh by just modifying the index of FILES in the `dirname` command for bash as noted in the comments):

```sh
# Expects a file path or newline-separated list of file paths

# Change Internal Field Separator (IFS) to newline,
# convert the input file paths(s) into an array (uses IFS),
# then revert IFS
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
FILES=($(echo $@))
IFS="$OLDIFS"

# If needed, e.g. to created a new sub-directory for output, 
# cd to the files' directory using the first item in the array
# (change index to 0 if bash -- zsh arrays start at 1)
cd "$(dirname "${FILES[1]}")"
# mkdir -p ./output # Example: create a directory for output

# Iterate over the files in the array
for FILE in "${FILES[@]}"; do
  # Do stuff with $FILE here
done
```

---

#### All together

Make sure in the Shell Script to choose "Input: Combined Text" and "Pass Input: as arguments"

[image]

Comment: You can use Shortcuts variables inside the script text. Ctrl-click the text field and insert a variable then use it as a string value.

Comment: Yes, it seems all loop logic is in shell script unnecessarily. This is not optimal solution at all then.